# HTML5 audio, testing if playing with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio, cookies

Alright so I have audio on my site, and I want a user to only be able to play one audio at a time, regardless of how many tabs or windows the user has open. So if the user starts a new song in a different tab, the other one stops playing. Quick disclaimer: I have it working right now, but it's not a good method. Right now I have it so that when the user starts an audio file, it creates a php session with a random id for the instance of the playback. Then if a song is playing, it constantly sends ajax to the server to see if the session id is the same as the song's playback id. if the id is not the same, the playback stops. So right now it's working 100% how I want it, but it's sending so many requests to the server so I know there has to be a better way with using cookies or something. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with HTML5 Web Storage and Cross-tab communication. Check out an example [here](https://truongtx.me/2014/06/16/cross-tab-communication-using-html5-dom-storage/) and h[ere](http://ponyfoo.com/articles/cross-tab-communication).

Comment: Ok so I tried to implement what you suggested but I can't get the session storage values in another tab / window. It seems to be only applying in one. If I have 3 songs running, each song(tab / window) has its own value for the session storage key I specified.

Comment: Do they happen to be on different domains?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using local storage and not session storage.

IE localStorage.setItem('bear','black');

Then in the next tab on the same website run localStorage.getItem('bear');

And you should see the results. Session storage only works on the same window, where as local storage persists through all tabs on the same domain.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I figured it out before I saw this but that's my fault haha. I got it working exactly the same as I had it before but with local storage. So Awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome to hear! Good luck!